# xcode 7.2 Linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode

I am having the devil of a time with an error in XCode 7.2  the full of the build error is as follows..

```
Ld /Users/skrite/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PivoTrac-endythvhjbfwtchiigrtipfugerp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PivoTrac.app/PivoTrac normal x86_64
cd /Users/skrite/XCode-Projects/PivoTrac
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.2
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -L/Users/skrite/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PivoTrac-endythvhjbfwtchiigrtipfugerp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/skrite/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PivoTrac-endythvhjbfwtchiigrtipfugerp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/skrite/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PivoTrac-endythvhjbfwtchiigrtipfugerp/Build/Intermediates/PivoTrac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PivoTrac.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PivoTrac.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.2 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/skrite/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PivoTrac-endythvhjbfwtchiigrtipfugerp/Build/Intermediates/PivoTrac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PivoTrac.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PivoTrac.swiftmodule /Users/skrite/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PivoTrac-endythvhjbfwtchiigrtipfugerp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/skrite/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PivoTrac-endythvhjbfwtchiigrtipfugerp/Build/Intermediates/PivoTrac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PivoTrac.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PivoTrac_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/skrite/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PivoTrac-endythvhjbfwtchiigrtipfugerp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PivoTrac.app/PivoTrac

ld: framework not found Realm for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

it is strange. I have reset my code from git a few times and there are a couple of times that it has worked (made the arrow go away) but usually not. It may have something to do with ios charts library that went missing.

The last time i got it working again was by removing (deleting) iosCharts from my project navigator, but part of it must still be there or misplaced because i did not get an error about "import Charts" and when i ran the app, it loaded a chart. However, as i am writing new code (only editing one file) the above error shows up again. I have been working on this since early yesterday. Thanks for any tips. I am very new at this.

Comment: did u set build active architecture to NO ?

Comment: Well, I just switched it to NO (it had nothing selected). and the link problem went away. But now it cannot find a module in the Charts library. Even after I tried to install it again.

Comment: did u include the chart library in the embedded binaries section ?